# Get Attributes XML in VB Net

Tags: xml, vb.net

How i can get value link2 or link3 in VB.net

(I use    node("link").Attributes("href").Value just get only 'link1')

```
<entry>
        <id>Title</id>
        <link href='link1' />
        <link href='link2' />
        <link href='link3' />
        <link href='link4' />
        <link href='link5' />
</entry>
<entry>
        <id>Title</id>
        <link href='link1' />
        <link href='link2' />
        <link href='link3' />
        <link href='link4' />
        <link href='link5' />
</entry>
```

My code:

```
    doc.Load(url_get)
    Dim elemList As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("entry")
    Dim node As XmlElement = Nothing
    For Each node In elemList
       'code....
    NEXT
```

Comment: You can use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). [VB.Net example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301220)

Comment: what is `node` in your sample code? It isn't clear what did you use to handle the XML, `XDocument`, `XElement`, `XmlDocument`, or anything else? Show your codes

Answer (score 1):

You can create an XElement from your XML snippet and then get the href attribute from the second and third link elements like this.

```
Dim ent As XElement = <entry>
                          <id>Title</id>
                          <link href='link1'/>
                          <link href='link2'/>
                          <link href='link3'/>
                          <link href='link4'/>
                          <link href='link5'/>
                      </entry>

Dim links As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = ent.<link>
Dim link2, link3 As String
If links.Count > 2 Then
    link2 = links(1).@href
    link3 = links(2).@href
End If
```

[Edit: based on a comment to another answer]. If you want to loop through links 2 through 3 (assuming they exist), you can use the following code:

```
Dim ent As XElement =
    <entry>
        <id>Title</id>
        <link href='link1'/>
        <link href='link2'/>
        <link href='link3'/>
        <link href='link4'/>
        <link href='link5'/>
    </entry>

For i As Integer = 1 To Math.Min(2, ent.<link>.Count - 1)
    Dim link As String = ent.<link>(i).@href
    'Do something with link
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have this:

```
    Dim xml As XElement =
        <entry>
            <id>Title</id>
            <link href='link1'/>
            <link href='link2'/>
            <link href='link3'/>
            <link href='link4'/>
            <link href='link5'/>
        </entry>
```

Then you could get the first and second values like this:

```
    Dim value1 As String = xml.<link>(0).@href
    Dim value2 As String = xml.<link>(1).@href
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dim xDoc as New XMLDocument
xDoc.LoadXML("<entry><id>Title</id><link href='link1' /><link href='link2' />" & 
    "<link href='link3' /><link href='link4' /><link href='link5' />" &
    "</entry>")
dim s As String = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("(/entry/link)[2]").Attributes("href").value
```

This gets the second link.

Or like this:

```
dim xn as XmlNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/entry/link")
dim s As String = xn(1).Attributes("href").value
```

This also gets the second one (0-based).

Comment: I have problem other,  how to i use your code in loop for?
(I'm just begin learing vb.net)

Comment: What do you mean with for loop, what do you want to loop through? You were asking for a solution without a for loop. The XmlNodeList however contains all the link elements (in my second example), you can loop through it.

Comment: I sorry, i mean is no loop all value of tag link. just get one or two value.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to get all `href` based on the codes you posted :

```
doc.Load(url_get)
Dim elemList As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("entry")
Dim node As XmlElement = Nothing
For Each node In elemList
   For Each href As XmlNode In node.SelectNodes("link/@href")
        Console.WriteLine(href.Value)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I test your code, it return null, this "entry.SelectNodes("link/@href")" i fix -> node.SelectNodes("link/@href") right?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Can you post content of node.OuterXml when the selectnodes returned null?